# Extract numbers from string using shell

Tags: command-line, bash

Using shell script, how do I extract two sets of numbers from a string like "R14C11"? I'd like to get the result as an AppleScript list.

```
R14C11 -> {14, 11}
R5C9   -> {5, 9}
```

"R" and "C" will be constants but the number of digits in each set of numbers can vary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to do this, one is to use `sed`

```
echo R5C9 | sed -E 's|R(.*)C(.*)|{\1, \2}|'
```

Or, if you want to ensure that only input with the correct format will be matched

```
echo R5C9 | sed -E 's|R([[:digit:]]+)C([[:digit:]]+)|{\1, \2}|'
```

Some explanations:

- `-E` enables extended regular expressions, which among other things makes the matching of the pattern easier
- `s|SOURCE|TARGET|` is the substitution command to transform `SOURCE` into `TARGET`
- `R([[:digit:]]+)C([[:digit:]]+)` is the source pattern we are looking for: An `R` followed by at least one digit `[[:digit:]]+` followed by `C` followed again by at least one digit
- The target replaces the matched source, with `\1` standing for the text matched within the first `()` in the source, `\2` for the second

---

You can also just use `bash` itself

```
[[ "R5C9" =~ R([0-9]+)C([0-9]+) ]] && echo "{${BASH_REMATCH[1]}, ${BASH_REMATCH[2]}}"
```

- `[[ "R5C9" =~ R([0-9]+)C([0-9]+) ]]` matches the text, with `R([0-9]+)C([0-9]+)` being basically the same as the source pattern above
- Matching parts within `()` get assigned to the shell array `BASH_REMATCH`
- The `echo` is only executed if the match (`[[ ... ]]`) was successfull, and then prints the reformatted expression (which is a bit confusing to read because the various `{}` mean different things...)

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, in its original form here sed returns a string of: "{5, 9}", not an actual Applescript list of integers: {5, 9}. I hacked it together though based on your answer. Thank you!